# Concatenate variable in string bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, concatenation, command-line-interface

Im killing the process in the port 4444, but this can change, i have the port in a variable PORT, but i cant find how to put this in the instruction

```
netstat -ntlp | awk '$4~/:*4444$/{gsub(/\/.*/,"",$NF);cmd="kill -9 "$NF;system(cmd)}'
```

I have tried with:

```
netstat -ntlp | awk '$4~/:*${PORT}$/{gsub(/\/.*/,"",$NF);cmd="kill -9 "$NF;system(cmd)}'
```

But it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables aren't expanded in single quotes, but you *don't* have to resort to double-quotes and their excessive escaping. Just get out of the single-quoted string!

```
netstat -ntlp | awk '$4~/:*'${PORT}'$/{gsub(/\/.*/,"",$NF);cmd="kill -9 "$NF;system(cmd)}'
```

See how `${PORT}` follows the close-quote from the first half, and precedes the start-quote from the second half.

Comment: Thanks i didnt know that about single and double quotes on cli, am new on this,

Answer (score 1):

Shell variables aren't expanded by the shell within single quotes. You'll have to surround your awk program with *double* quotes `"`, and do a bunch more escaping of the enclosed program because bash will be interpreting all those embedded `$` as variable expansions.

Comment: You'll probably have to expand the * and quotes inside that string as well. See here for more on Bash string escapes: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: i have been trying putting \ before the others $, and the old ", like this, netstat -ntlp | awk "\$4~/:\*$PORT$/{gsub(/\/.*/,\"\",\$NF);cmd=\"kill -9 \"\$NF;system(cmd)}"

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not expanded in single-quoted (`'`) strings.  Try double-quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes and escape the other '$'.